# I am trying to design Laravel 8 login page but not found where is it. I am use Laravel 8 and AUTH package is " Jetstream inertia

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

I am trying to design Laravel 8 login page but it was found in button of the login page and I want to see it in the middle . I am use Laravel 8

[image]

Comment: Welcome, you forgot to ask a question. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use another method

```
cd project

composer require laravel/ui --dev

npm install && npm run dev

php artisan ui:auth


php artisan migrate
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).